# Microsoft Internet Transfer Control failing over https

Tags: https, vb6

I have an old VB app that uses the Microsoft Internet Transfer Control (or Inet) to read info from a web page over HTTPS. It is installed on a number of Windows 10 machines and it works fine on all of them except for one. On this machine, when the call is made over HTTPS, the response comes back blank. The request never makes it to the web server because there is no entry for it in the IIS logs. Calls over HTTP to the same URL work just fine, only the HTTPS call has this problem.

I suspect the problem is with TLS 1.0. That protocol is disabled on the web server. I'm aware that older browsers, including old versions of IE, require TLS 1.0. *Is there a setting that controls whether Inet can support TLS 1.1+?* I did check Internet Options and "Use TLS 1.1" and "Use TLS 1.2" are already checked, so maybe these settings don't apply to Inet and I need to look elsewhere. *Or is the problem something else?*

Here is the code that uses Inet to make the HTTPS call. It's pretty straightforward.

```
response = Inet1.OpenURL("https://my_site/some_page")
' response is blank
```

Comment: You might be "looking in the wrong place" because if this was the problem it wouldn't work on any of the machines.

Comment: I doubt the fix will be in the code but I wonder if there's some obscure setting in Windows on the broken machine that is causing the problem

Comment: I know that I have issues with client machines that do not have the option in IE use SSL 2.0 checked in the Advanced tab under Internet Options.  Try that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Experimenting with internet properties I found that unchecking "Use HTTP 1.1", leave "HTTP 1.1 through proxy connections" checked, fixes the problem. Have to close your program and restart it if you make the change while it's running. Don't have to reboot your PC. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if you disabled the TLS 1.0 in the WebServer then it will not work in the machines those are supported till TLS 1.0.
VB browser uses IE7 by default. If the HTTPS link works on the machine regular browser then you need to check for document mode settings otherwise you need to enable TLS 1.0 in the webserver.